What XCCY pricing inputs do large market makers use for FX Forwards/Swaps?
While there are a few similar questions on here regarding FXF pricing, I was unable to find something that answers this directly.
To be more specific, it's clear that as per CIP, the pricing inputs for an FX swap are:

Spot rate $S_t$
Interest rate for the base (domestic) currency $r_d$
Interest rate for the quoted (foreign) currency $r_f$
Cross currency basis $z$

As an amateur practitioner, I would construct an OIS curve for $r_d$, $r_f$ using quotes from market instruments (futures, IRS)*.
Subsequently, I would strip out a cross currency basis ($z$) curve, using market observable FX swap points as my primary input for tenors up to 2-3Y, after which observed XCCY quotes take over.
With these three curves, as well as a spot rate, I should be able to reprice FX forwards to market for any date on the curve (forgetting for a moment about month-end turns and other idiosyncratic points).
This is where I run into a conceptual gap--I assume that price makers cannot use electronic FX swap quotes as inputs for market observed cross currency basis in the short end, since they are effectively the ones pricing them. Are they using quotes from voice brokerage? FX futures exchanges? a proprietary blend?

What exactly should be different for XCCY, compared to spot FX, fwds, IV, OTC bond quotes, ...

To be blunt, we make them up - generally as an implied yield over sofr if usd is the main base currency quote. This is fundamentally true for almost every derivative price, at some level the price comes from where some person thinks it should be. The machinery for creating that price may be different, SABR parameters or ATM vols and RR quotes but some person has to decide where they are prepared to pay or receive 3 month FX rates or vol etc and adjust those prices given interbank and large corporate / NBFI flows.
